# Insert string from file to TextArea Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def isiDataFile(self,namaFile):
    isiFile = open(namaFile)
    content = isiFile.read().lower()
    words = re.findall('\w+',content)

    print words

    self.textFile.delete('1.0',END)
    for i in words:
        self.textFile.insert('1.0',i+"\n")

    isiFile.close()
```

I wanna print some string from file .txt to textArea (Tkinter gui).
Example, my string is

```
"ular melingkar, lalu terbang. harimau berjalan di atas air. eh, kenapa hujan atas? bukan sungai mendaki"
```

but, when i insert the string to textarea, the result :

```
>>> mendaki, sungai, bukan, atas, hujan, kenapa, eh, air, atas, di, berjalan, harimau, terbang, lalu, melingkar, ular.
```

it look, somehow, be reverse.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the order of the words is reversing is that you are inserting each word at the beginning:

```
    self.textFile.insert('1.0',i+"\n")
```

I would take `words` and build a single string, for example:

```
words = " ".join(words)
```

and then do the insert all at once instead of within a for-loop.

The other option would be to perform each insert within the for-loop at the end, rather than the beginning:

```
for word in words:
    self.textFile.insert(END, word)
```

Comment: Also `'1.0'` is probably not a valid first argument for `insert`, I'd guess it needs to be an integer.

Comment: @figs: you are incorrect. The index is a string of the form _line.character_